# Problem with Login after register by Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, passwords

When I register in laravel ,I can't login by that account.
This is my controller code:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
                'phone' => 'required|numeric|digits:11|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            ]);
            $data = $request->all();

            //check unique phone
            $usersCount = User::where('phone', $data['phone'])->count();
            if ($usersCount > 0) {
                return back()->with('flash_message_error', 'این شماره قبلا ثبت شده است');
            } else {
                $user = new User;
                $user->name = $data['name'];
                $user->phone = $data['phone'];
                $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
                $user->save();
                if (Auth::attempt(['phone' => $data['phone'], 'password' => $data['password']])) {
                    Session::put('frontSession', $data['phone']);
                    return redirect('profile');
                }
            }
        }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $request->validate([
                'phone' => 'required|numeric|digits:11',
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ]);
            $data = $request->all();
            if (Auth::attempt(['phone' => $data['phone'], 'password' => $data['password']])) {
                Session::put('frontSession', $data['phone']);
                return redirect('/');
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'Not Valid');
            }
        }
    }
```

**And this is blade:**

```
<form action="{{route('userLogin')}}" name="loginForm" method="POST">
@csrf
<input class="form-control" type="number" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone number"/>
<input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>

<small  style="direction: ltr">
<label for="remember" class="form-check-label">remember me</label>
<input id="remember" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
</small>
<button type="submit" class="btn iren-btn btn-block">login</button>
</form>

<form id="registerForm" name="registerForm" action="{{url('user-register')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="name"/>
<input class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" type="number" placeholder="phone"/>
<input class="form-control mb-2" id="myPassword"
name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" style="direction: ltr"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn iren-btn btn-block">register</button>
</form>
```

after login it errors 'Not Valid' because of password.When I change password in database by copying from another field that I created by db:seed, it works.

Comment: Laravel includes user creation and authentication out of the box. Just do: `php artisan make:auth`. Rolling your own is not recommended.

Comment: I did that , but I have this problem again

Comment: You would need to build on top of Laravel's Auth to include any additional functionality you need. That command is only going to work for a fresh install of Laravel. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $request->validate([
            'phone' => 'required|numeric|digits:11',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
        $data = $request->all();
        if (Auth::attempt(['phone' => $data['phone'], 'password' => $data['password']])) {
            Session::put('frontSession', $data['phone']);
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'Not Valid');
        }
    }
}
```

with :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $request->validate([
            'phone' => 'required|numeric|digits:11',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
        $data = $request->all();
        $user = User::where('phone', $data['phone'])->first();

        if ($user) {
            if(Hash::check($data['password'], $user->password))
            {
                Auth::login($user);
                Session::put('frontSession', $data['phone']);
                return redirect('/');
            }
            else{
                 return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'password does not match');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_error', 'Not Valid');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing change. 'Not Valid' again

Comment: can you check if the user exists with phone and password you are trying ?

Comment: user exists and it's password is 123456, when I copy hashed password from another user that I created by db:seed and it's password is 123456 too, it is working. I think problem is from hashing.

Comment: how can I figure that.because I input 123456. my site language is not english, is that related?

Comment: you need to update the password $user['password'] = bcrypt('123456'); $user->save(); and then try again

Comment: I have this code :
$user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);

this is hashed pass that is working:
$2y$10$7IHuOugUBkYFSEu1hrACIuY2odHozPPCf9KnIPqx5OEUxq9Nmy.jK
and this is not working after register:
$2y$10$DLCH56qY7kCWEDuEs5h4auW5O4M2elNBMp0amJENT74ozQkJFE3.y

Comment: two hashed values need not have same string, they can still match

Comment: but when I copy first to second in db , it will work